# Error to sync KSoap2

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am trying to synk my KSoap2 library but when I click on synchronize ksoap2 ... these tell me it was a successful synchronization but when I try to use this it does not show the tags and it marks in red the `SoapObject`

Does any body have the same problem? Or how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved i see these tutorial an works for me

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/consuming-web-services-with-ksoap--mobile-21242